# Cobol Simulator for Windows

Tags: programming-languages, simulator, cobol, platform

I am new to Cobol proramming. I cant own a mainframe system. But I want to practice cobol programming. Can anyone tell me any simulator or any platform on which I could work for Cobol program.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try [OpenCOBOL](http://opencobol.org/). It's an open-source COBOL compiler for Linux, Mac, and Windows.

Answer (score 4):

[Micro Focus COBOL](http://visualcobol.microfocus.com/your-role/developers/) is another COBOL compiler for Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Or, if you really want to go old school while practicing some mainframe COBOL, try Hercules.

Hercules System/370 emulator, with a 1970s cut of OS360 and MVS/MVT. Run JCL and UCOB, an IBM COBOL circa 1968 standard.

Then, perhaps, utilize the Hercules system and a virtual OS/360 to learn up on other big iron concepts and *ancient, historical, dot-connecting* details.

*From what little I understand, IBM has allowed a tape archive of pre 1971 OS360 to live on the internet as it was built from sources produced before changes to default copyright rules, and no explicit copyright notices were attached.  I can only assume IBM allows this out of niceness, and can go after people abusing the privileges to these early open sources.  Plus, this may well be spreading misinformation, not claiming to be in the know.*

Google **Hercules OpenCOBOL OS/360** for some article links.  As keeper of the OpenCOBOL FAQ, I was looking for some early COBOL samples, UCOB fit that bill fairly nicely.  Running the 1970 source codes, wow, it's fun being old.  The terminal session samples posted are very GNU/Linux specific, but Hercules is reported to work on Windows, and most of the how-to and where-is should apply.

Realizing that attempting to avoid a link and suggest a google search, likely just tainted the google search, so http://opencobol.org/archive/1444.txt

Answer (score 2):

TinyCobol at http://tiny-cobol.sourceforge.net/ is available.

Comment: Unfortunately, the web site says: "Development of TinyCOBOL, by the current maintainer, has come to an end. Consequently version 0.66 will be the final release.

Anyone who would like to further develop TinyCOBOL, and become the project maintainer, please post a request to the official mailing list. All applicants will be considered. Fluency in English would be beneficial, but it is not a prerequisite."

Answer (score 1):

[COBOL .NET using Microsoft Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver/mainframe/training.mspx)

[Installing COBOL FOR Visual Studio 2008](http://www.bgsu.edu/departments/compsci/docs/cobol.html)